# Oracle regexp_replace: Don't replace the first character, replace others

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing a sql, and I am using regexp_replace function for this.

My aim is to replace the characters like `'|', '\'` etc with '-'.

The problem which I am facing is that it replaces the '+', which is at the beginning.

For eg:

The phone number is: `+49 |0| 941 78878544`

I have to repalce the '|' with '-'.

My code is this:`SELECT  regexp_replace(phone,'\D','-') FROM PHONE_TBL WHERE EMPLID = employee;`

I get the output as: `-49--0--941-78878544`

This code replaces the `space` , along with the `'+'` in the beginning.

I want the '+' to remain, if it is there in the beginning, and if phone numbers have spaces among them, that also should remain.

For '+', I have figured out i should match the beginning of the string, then,must check for non numeric digit, and then escape, but not able to code.

And for space in between, similar approach.

Any help in this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace all instances of '\' and '|' with '-', use the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[\|\]','-') 
FROM phone_tbl 
WHERE emplid = employee;
```

The square brackets define a set of characters to match. The '\|' means match a pipe character; the '\' means match a backslash character. If you want to replace more characters other than backslash and pipe then you add them between the square brackets.

Comment: Means, to repalce '/', i shall this: REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[\|/\]','-')